# The Internet is Your Oyster

Tags: word-usage, slang

Why they say the Internet is your oyster when they mean, I guess,  you can find abundant resources to solve your problem?

---

Update : It has [an origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21757)  which I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived from "the world is your oyster", yes, it means something like you say. The Internet has abundant resources for learning information and being entertained and communicating. Whether or not this will help you solve your problem, I don't know, depends upon the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right you have abundant resources. I guess it's like the world is your oyster which means: One can do anything one wants in life.  *You have so much talent at such a young age—the world is your oyster!*